# Converting a Lua file object to a C FILE*

Tags: c, file-io, lua, ffi, luajit

I'm building a wrapper using LuaJIT and FFI. I have a C library with a function that takes a `FILE*` as a parameter. In a Lua function within which I open a file using `io.open()`. Is there a way to cast, convert, or extract from the Lua file object to a C `FILE*`? This seems like it should be straightforward but I can't find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

LuaJIT head will automatically convert a Lua file handle to a FILE * (well, void *).

http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/an-admittedly-lazy-programmer-question,4